# Categories In English version showing not canonical URL, instead shows query search result

Tags: wp-query, categories, custom-field, search, plugin-wpml

I have a multilingual site (WPML), it has Hebrew and English languages. But for some reason in English version categories showing as query string instead of just pass it through URL. What issue can cause this error?

[image]

Category loop in Hebrew - works

[image]

In Hebrew version its working. But in English - not
[image]
[image]

Comment: Query string shows like ?s=Caps+%28Category%29&post_type=product instead of /category/caps

Comment: So no answer about this issue?